# Just 'carry' for 'carry weapons' and just 'lift' instead of 'lift weights'. What linguistic phenomenon is it?

Tags: verbs, terminology, transitive-verbs

There are English verbs that can be used without an object while meaning a certain object. E.g.

- Carry = carry weapons
- Lift = lift weights
- Use = use drugs
- Possibly, ‘investigate’ (an incident, a crime, a statement) as well.

Some examples I saw:

> California may issue permits to carry if a person meets the requirements.

> For years I lifted just because I loved to lift.

> The FBI was called in to investigate.

This is what I’m wondering:

1. Any more examples that spring to your mind?
2. Is there a word or a term in Linguistics for this sort of phenomenon?

I found and read a few articles about null objects / context null objects. They mention examples like ‘Beat [ø] until stiff’. Are my examples the same phenomenon?

Thank you.

Comment: Implied object, perhaps.

Comment: _I gave at the office, He hasn't eaten yet._ Any predictable generic object can be deleted with many verbs. There are several phenomena involved, including recipe directions, as you note. Another is label text: _Close door before starting_ on the dryer controls, but _Close before starting dryer_ on the dryer door, or _Take with food_ on a pill bottle. Verbs like _eat_ always mean _eat something_, though _drink_ can refer either to any liquid or to alcoholic liquids. It's a complex topic.

Comment: To answer your basic question of, "What linguistic phenomenon is it[called]?"  In layman's terms, the phenomenon is called "verbing" or in linguistic terms, "denominalization." The phenomenon is prolific. The Romans did it. The Assyrians did it.  Benjamin Franklin hated it. Samuel Johnson tolerated it.  More examples? "Give me a ring" (the phone rings. So, "ring" =  call me on the phone). It's quite endless and prolific, and those proficient in Russian, Chinese, Japanese...state they all do it, too.

Comment: @SteveB053 - I don’t think he’s asking about verbing nouns.  He’s asking about “lifting” vs “lifting weights”

Comment: This happens constantly. "Do you drive?" A car is implied. It can sometimes be a marker of in group status -- leaving out the word signifying that you're part of the group that knows what you're referring to.  Even "I don't drink" implying drinking alcohol.

Comment: For Jim: commentor stated "...There are English verbs that can be used without an object while meaning a certain object..."  There are millions of examples (even Chaucer includes them) where verb use without an object occurs. Example: an invention is no longer new & grow common in use. It happens to both verbs and nouns.  Thomas Edison's "Edison miniature incandescent electric lamps" - unique invention--became prolific, common.  "Electric lamps" by 1913.  Electricity; unique, became common.  Called "light bulbs" today in 2021.  The linguistic phenomenon is above.

Comment: You can also call it: reduction. Once a phrase becomes very well known, people just start using shorter versions of it. **California may issue permits to *carry [a gun]* if a person meets the requirements**. **For years, I lifted [*weights*]**. By the way, the third one is not one of these.

Comment: It tells you something if a person uses *winter* as a verb. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The "linguistic phenomenon" is know **ambitransitive verbs**.

These verbs, and there are many of them, may appear with or without an object but, can always have an object assumed.

e.g.

He ate

He ate a meal/apple/whole pig.

More simply, "something or someone" can be added after the verb.

In the examples you give, of course, the context implies the object, whereas normally, e.g. He ate, we do not know what he ate but he ate something.

Carry = carry weapons - context Police, politicians, concern over guns.

Lift = lift weights - context restricted to people who lift weights.

Use = use drugs - context police and drugs users.

It does this by dint of the repetitive and constant use in that context.

Comment: Yes, these are all agentive ambitransitive usages. But Visser also mentions situations where a DO isn't easily recoverable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Does "do" need to be recoverable in "How do (periphrastic) you do."? To do = to fare - I feel that, in this sense, "do" is not ambitransitive but intransitive.

Comment: As Visser says, there are grey areas  [which probably change shape and shade over time]: 'Occasionally the [candidate] object is so vague that the verb is virtually an intransitive one, especially in those combinations where it has acquired a [c] [novel sense].' The same thing happens with metaphor, where say 'umbrella term' would not be considered a metaphorical usage by some because [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/umbrella-term) say gives a 'literal' listing of the term ('umbrella term' always having had the non-downpour sense).

Answer (score 0):

Visser, in *[An historical syntax of the English language](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oZ03AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%22many+verbs%22+%22construed+with+an+object%22+Visser&source=bl&ots=oMDc1dyKXn&sig=ACfU3U1KBWuZ42KEQwt5Rf26KMUZT8jyDQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22many%20verbs%22%20%22construed%20with%20an%20object%22%20Visser&f=false)* [§152: Transitive Verbs used Absolutely] has

> - [M]any verbs that are usually construed with an object are often used without this object when it may be inferred [a] from the situation …
>   or [b] from the [lexical] context …. Occasionally the [candidate] object
>   is so vague that the verb is virtually an intransitive one, especially
>   in those combinations where it has acquired a [c] [novel sense].
> - [a] 'Drink, John, drink!'
> - [b] 'Shall I help you to carry the tray?' ... 'No, I can manage.'
> - [c1] 'The door gives onto the garden.'
> - [c2] 'How do you do!'

[adjusted slightly]

Of course, one man's 'easily inferrable from the global/lexical context' is another man's headache. 'You *must* eat!' is far more widely understood than 'He lifted in his earlier years'.

Answer (score 0):

**These verbs and nouns are said to collocate.** In other words, be found at the same "location".

Relevant Wikipedia entry

> Collocations are partly or fully fixed expressions that become
> established through repeated context-dependent use. Such terms as
> 'crystal clear', 'middle management', 'nuclear family', and 'cosmetic
> surgery' are examples of collocated pairs of words.
>
> **Collocations can be in a syntactic relation (such as verb–object: 'make' and 'decision')**, lexical relation (such as antonymy), or they
> can be in no linguistically defined relation. **Knowledge of
> collocations is vital for the competent use of a language: a
> grammatically correct sentence will stand out as awkward if
> collocational preferences are violated. This makes collocation an
> interesting area for language teaching.**

Corpus linguists specify a key word in context (KWIC) and identify the words immediately surrounding them. This gives an idea of the way words are used.

The processing of collocations involves a number of parameters, the most important of which is the measure of association, which evaluates whether the co-occurrence is purely by chance or statistically significant. Due to the non-random nature of language, most collocations are classed as significant, and the association scores are simply used to rank the results. Commonly used measures of association include mutual information, t scores, and log-likelihood.[2][3]

[collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)

[bolding mine]

Examples:

- make a decision [ok], do a decision [buzzer]
- be [some age"ten-years old] [ok], have some age [buzzer: have ten years]

When an object is missing in a verb+object collocation, it is because the writer has decided that the culture will approve it and recognize it. In "carry weapons", readers will fill it in in their minds.

Comment: No. OP is asking about those verbs that may drop objects, not those that regularly associate with a restricted subset of logically available objects. Thus 'make/take' in 'make/take a decision', but never just 'make/take'.